# Пифагоровы тройки for python

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу в пайтоне.
На вход программы подается число x. Найдите все пифагоровы тройки, такие, чтобы c < x и выведите их количество для заданного x.
Есть какие-то попытки...но это совсем неверно...

```
k = int(input())
x=0
for i in range (1,k):
    i2==i*i
    for j in range (i,k):
        j2==j*j
        c==(i2+j2)**0.5
        if c>=k:
            break
        if c==int(c):
            x+=1
```

Comment: У вас есть какие-нибудь идеи? Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание — здесь не решают задачи. Но помогают их решить. Вы можете добавить в вопрос ваш код (даже нерабочий), нажав кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибки в том, что вместо оператора присваивания `=`, используете оператор сравнения `==`
ну и надо вывести посчитанное количество

если исправить, то получится

```
k = int(input())
x = 0
for i in range (1,k):
    i2=i*i
    for j in range (i,k):
        j2=j*j
        c=(i2+j2)**0.5
        if c>=k:
            break
        if c==int(c):
            x+= 1
            print(a, b, int(c))

print('Всего найдено троек:', x)
```